# libxml converts accented characters into backslash x escapes. Json is not happy

Tags: ruby, json, libxml2

I have the following attribute in an xml node I'm reading with libxml. It prints out normally with the accented character if I print out reader.node.

```
reader = XML::Reader.new(File.open("somefile.xml", "r"))
reader.read
reader.read
...
p reader.node

=> ... Full_Name="Univisión Network - East Feed" ...
```

If I do this, though, it comes out escaped.

```
p reader.node["Full_Name"]
=> "Univisi\xC3\xB3n Network - East Feed"
```

And when I try to convert this value to json laater, I get the following error.

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Here is the xml line in the document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

I don't have control over the xml document itself. How can I get that unicode character back into json, or into a format json understands?

**EDIT**: Oh, I forgot to mention - this is how it looks in the actual XML document

```
Full_Name="Univisi&#243;n Network - East Feed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
so i've been trying figuring this out for quite some time now. funny thing: your code works without error in ruby 1.8 (at least here). so i think the error has to do with ruby 1.9's new encoding handling. somehow it cannot figure out that the parsed and read XML is in (libxml's internal) utf-8 format (the document encoding doesn't matter here: in 1.8 it works with both iso-8859-1 and utf-8, even with the wrong xml encoding declaration). instead, it treats it as ASCII-8BIT, or BINARY. in other words, it doesn't know the encoding. which is why `to_json` fails trying to convert it to utf-8.

your easiest way to solve it might be to downgrade to ruby 1.8.

alternatively, your approach of `force_encoding('UTF-8')` seems to be reasonable.
**EDIT END**

you can try passing the proper encoding to the reader:

```
reader = XML::Reader.new(File.open("somefile.xml", "r"), 
  XML::Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
```

Comment: Wait, I thought I wanted to force it to use UTF-8? Wouldn't i want `reader = XML::Reader.new(File.open("somefile.xml", "r"), :encoding => XML::Encoding::UTF_8)` ?   I still get the error pasting your code in blindly, and setting it to UTF_8 doesn't seem to change it (when I ask for it's encoding it still gives ISO_8859_1)

Comment: so what is the real encoding of `somefile.xml` (regardless of the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to check. `file --mime somefile.xml` gives `application/xml; charset=us-ascii`

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm still completely lost as to why I couldn't figure out the "Right" way to do it, but [this thread](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2313) helped to find the `force_encoding` method on the String class. Since my code involves copying attributes into a hash anyway, it's not a big deal to call `force_encoding` when I copy the value.

I doubly made sure I had saved the file as UTF-8, and put the right xml declaration at the top. It still failed.

Anyway, until I can figure out how to fix the actual problem, this code fixed it.

```
  object = { type: node.name }      
  node.attributes.each do |attribute|
    name = attribute.name.gsub /_/,""
    value = attribute.value.force_encoding('UTF-8')

    object[name] = value
  end
```

Note this would not be appropriate if I weren't already needing to copy the node into a hash, since it definitely wouldn't be worth all the trouble. If I then do

```
object.to_json
```

It works without a problem. Thanks for all your help ax! Do you have any idea how I can force the encoding on the xml?

Comment: Well, Ruby 1.9's been hard on you here.

Comment: The problem is that the XML document is just plain WRONG.  It claims to be ISO-8859-1 when it's actually UTF-8.  You are fixing it by using force-encoding.  Not being a Ruby developer, I don't know if you can force the XML parser to ignore the declared encoding and use UTF-8 for the entire document.

Comment: @Julik - I'd say. @Jim - yeah, I that's what I thought too, but I changed the declaration at the top AND made sure it was saved as UTF-8 (using textmate), AND forced the encoding (at least according to the documentation for the libxml library) and it's still being weird. Oh well

Answer (score 0):

> If it do this, though, it comes out escaped.

Not quite.  What you're seeing is UTF-8 output interpreted as a string of bytes.

The problem is that your XML document *says* it's ISO-8859-1, while it is really UTF-8.  Fix the encoding problems and it should work.

Comment: Do you know off the top of your head how to override the xml document's encoding? Again, I can't change the xml document.

Comment: This is not working: `reader = XML::Reader.io(file, :encoding => XML::Encoding::UTF_8)` When I ask for the document's encoding it's still returning the old one

Comment: it should be `XML::Encoding::ISO_8859_1` - see my answer.

Comment: I still get the error even when setting the encoding to ISO_8859_1. Sorry I'm so confused here